# If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, does $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\int |f(x-s) - f(x)| dm$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

So if it were to exist, clearly it is nonnegative. Then for $s\in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$\int |f(x-s) -f(x)|dm(x) \leq \int|f(x-s)|dm(x) + \int|f(x)|dm(x)$$
because $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. My intuition is that since the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, these integrals should be the same. However, I'm not sure how to prove that, or even if my answer is correct.

edit: fixed my inequality.

Comment: Yes, those integrals on the right are equal. But then their difference is zero, but the left side can be strictly positive.

Comment: Try to proof it for continous functions which have compact support and use their density in $ L^1 $.

Comment: you should put a variable of integration

Answer (score 1):

$\int|f(x-s)|dm=\int|f(x)|dm$, so it is independent of $s$.  Therefore $\lim_{s\to \infty}\int|f(x-s)|dm$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the answer if $f$ is supported in some interval?